# How to change file Url in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem. I want change the url in media files, but this input is disabled.

How to change this url?

[image]

Comment: That is the actual URL of where the file lives. Do you want to change where the files physically lives or mask it so that the users see a different url than this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try going to Settings / General and change the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL). Then click on Save changes.

Then go to Settings / Permalink Settings and click on Save changes.
Not sure if this is what you asked.

If this is not working, you could try updating your database.

1. Access PhpMyAdmin
2. Select your database
3. In wp_options look for the "siteurl" field and change it for whatever you like.
4. In wp_options look for the "Home" field and change it for whatever you like. It should be obviously the same as "siteurl".
5. Select all the tables of your database.
6. Click on SQL at the top of the interface.
7. Enter the following SQL request

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content =
 REPLACE(post_content, 'http://www.yoursite1.com',
 'http://www.yoursite2.com');`

1. In your Wordpress admin panel, go to Settings / General
2. Change the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) to your new URL. Save changes.
3. Go to Settings / Permalink Settings without changing anything and click on Save changes.

Comment: I changed the url in Setting but in files do'nt take the change

Comment: This answer is wrong. This is how you update the whole site url, not the url of a media post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Media File URL in WordPress. There are three steps involved:

1. Log in to your SFTP, navigate to your `wp-content/uploads/` directory, and rename the file.
2. Edit the file **guid** and  in MySQL. Filter the post data using the following query:

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_id = 123 AND post_type = 'attachment' AND post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg';`

3. Edit the relevant post metadata values in **_wp_attached_file** and **_wp_attachment_metadata** by fetching and editing data with the query:

`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 123 AND meta_key IN ('_wp_attached_file', '_wp_attachment_metadata');`

Be aware that sometimes the value of `_wp_attachment_metadata` are serialized, so you must use the PHP [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to edit the data and [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it again.